# How do I reverse a set of comma delimited strings and return them in the original order in PHP?

Tags: php

This is the code I have so far. I just started learning PHP today and I'm not sure why my code isn't working.

```
<?php

function backwards($input)
{
    $str = $input;
    $revStr = "";
    $str = explode(",",$str);
    for($x = 0; $x < strlen($str); $x++){
        $revStr .= strrev($str[$x]);
    }
    return $revStr;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit: Here is an example input

```
Php,Arrays,Mysql
```

here is what i would like the output to be:

```
phP,syarrA,lqsyM
```

edit2:

Figured it out. Made a few minor edits. Not sure if it's the most efficient code but it works.

```
<?php

function backwards($input)
{
    $str = $input;
    $revStr = "";
    $str = explode(",",$str);
    for($x = 0; $x < count($str); $x++){
        if($x == count($str) - 1){
            $revStr .= strrev($str[$x]);
        }
        else{
            $revStr .= strrev($str[$x]) . ",";
        }
    }
    return $revStr;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some example string

Comment: `strlen()` return the length of string, what you pass inside is an array, what you want is `count()`

Comment: I have added the answer on the basis of provided link, Please check.

Comment: [Why can't I mark my title as Solved?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-cant-i-mark-my-title-as-solved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the string length of an array inside of your for loop. Also, a custom function is unnecessary, PHP provides us with [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php).

But if you would like to use your own:

```
function backwards($input)
{
    $str = $input;
    $revStr = "";
    $str = explode(",",$str);
    for($x = 0; $x < count($str); $x++){
        $revStr .= strrev($str[$x]);
    }
    return $revStr;
}

$string = "Php,Arrays,Mysql";
echo backwards($string);
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

Edit, I see you now included an example.
Use array_map and strrev to reverse the words.
Use explode and Implode to make the words array and back to string.

```
echo implode(",", array_map(function($part){ return strrev($part);},explode(",", $str)));
```

https://3v4l.org/tr7d6

---

<strike>I believe you should use array_reverse on the exploded string.

Then you can implode it back to a string.</strike>

```
$str = "apple,orange,tomato";

$arr = explode(",", $str);
$arr =array_reverse($arr);
echo implode(",", $arr); //tomato,orange,apple
```

https://3v4l.org/Hvd9m

Or, slightly messier but compact:

```
echo implode(",", array_reverse(explode(",", $str)));
```

https://3v4l.org/LTu90

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) instead of `strlen` and also need to take reversed string into array and then convert it into string.

You can try this code :

```
<?php

function backwards($input)
{
    $str = $input;
    $revStr = array();
    $str = explode(",", $str);
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($str); $x++) {
        $revStr[] = strrev($str[$x]);
    }
    return implode(',', $revStr);
}
$str = "Php,Arrays,Mysql";
var_dump(backwards($str));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$str[0]` in for loop syntax.

```
like this => for($x = 0; $x < strlen($str[0]); $x++)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just some modification and you got your desired output. You can use `explode` and `implode` function of `php` with `array_push` to get your result:

```
<?php

$string = "Php,Arrays,Mysql";

function backwards($input)
{
    $str = $input;
    $revStr = array();
    $str = explode(",", $str);
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($str); $x++) {
        array_push($revStr, strrev($str[$x]));
    }
    return implode(',', $revStr);
}

$result =backwards($string);

echo $result;

?>
```

You can check the demo [here](https://3v4l.org/KIhRb)